# Como converter texto em arquivo para número com casas decimais?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, matemática, conversão

Tenho estes dados escritos no ficheiro de texto "000001010" (só tem este dado), mas queria que quando fosse para a variável fosse assim 10,10.

Eu estou a ler os dados do ficheiro assim:

```
var linhas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\teste\pedro.txt");
```

Comment: Mas qual é a regra, jovem? Os dois últimos sempre vão ser a parte decimal?

Comment: @LINQ Vou tentar explicar melhor, por exemplo se for 000000010 isto corresponde a 0,10 se for 000010000 isto corresponde a 100 entendeu ?

Comment: Isso já eu já tinha entendido no início. Enfim, você quer estes valores como numéricos ou como string?

Comment: @LINQ numéricos

Comment: [Pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248634/18246)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pela regra descrita: é só converter o número pra inteiro e dividir por 100.

Aproveitei pra fazer com LINQ, assim cada linha do arquivo vai retornar um item para a lista `valores`.

```
var valores = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\teste\pedro.txt")
                  .Select(l => (decimal)Convert.ToInt32(l) / 100)
                  .ToList();

foreach(var val in valores)
    Console.WriteLine(val);
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IamDrJ)</sup>

Considerando que cada arquivo terá apenas uma linha, seria melhor fazer assim:

```
var strVal = File.ReadAllLines("C:\teste\pedro.txt")[0];
decimal valor = Convert.ToInt32(strVal) / 100m;
```

Comment: Considerando que cada ficheiro só vai ter uma linha não vale a pena ser uma lista ou tem mesmo de ser uma lista ?

Comment: @PedroAzevedo Não precisa não. Você pode por um `0` depois de `ToList` se quiser continuar usando LINQ, senão posso dar uma sugestão melhor.

Comment: vou testar esta mas eu não preciso de lista porque o ficheiro tem sempre só uma linha

Comment: @PedroAzevedo Eu adicionei no final da resposta uma alternativa **_=)_**

Comment: Muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

Partido do princípio que o formato é sempre este e estará sempre correto pode fazer:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var campo = "000001010";
        decimal valor = ToInt32(campo) / 100M;
        WriteLine(valor);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5YDSWJ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qv9EFc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/DecimalScaling.cs).

Se tem um elemento único no arquivo basta ler assim:

```
File.ReadAllLines("C:\teste\pedro.txt")[0];
```

Como o método [`ReadAllLines()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_) retorna um *array* com todas as linhas de texto do arquivo e só tem uma linha basta pegar o primeiro elemento. Não precisa fazer outras manipulação porque a linha não contém outra informação.